# class not finding namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

When I try to make an class in my H file, and I include another H file that has an namespace in it that I need to use, it will say its undeclared and that the namespace isn't a class or a namespace.

The class:

```
#include "interfaces.hpp"

class i_game_event_listener2 {
public: 
    virtual ~i_game_event_listener2(void) {};
    virtual void fire_game_event( i_game_event *event ) = 0;
    int debug_id = 42;
    void init() {
         interfaces::event_manager->add_listener(this, "player_death", false);
    }
};
```

The namespace `interfaces.hpp`:

```
namespace interfaces {
    inline i_game_event_manager2* event_manager;
}
```

The errors that I get:

- 'interfaces' is not a class or a namespace.
- 'event_manager' undeclared identifier.

Comment: If you are having trouble adding the code, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . If you are still stuck, search for your error message on https://meta.stackoverflow.com and https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you writing C++? If so please post your `#include` statements when you edit your question.

Comment: im writing C++, and the include its just #include "interfaces.hpp"

Comment: Can I suggest that make your question self-contained by clicking the 'edit' link above, to follow the example of the best questions on Stack Overflow? All the information in your screenshots and comment needs to be in your question if you want to attract good answers.

Comment: As you will see from your console game question, it is really important to include all the relevant code in the post. Pls don't link to screenshots of code.

Comment: ok i re writed my question

Comment: What command do you use to build this? (I think there may be an error in your build command).

Answer (score 0):

I can only reproduce something similar to this if I remove the include directive, or if I misspell the name of the file.

Check that the include directive is *exactly*:

```
 #include "interfaces.hpp"
```